# Play-Authenticate logout redirect

Tags: playframework, play-authenticate

I have integrated the Play-Authenticate module in my Play 2.0.4 project. There are two views to my project, a conventional web view and a mobile view. When the application logs out it just returns to the index page. In the routes table I see that the logout functionality points towards this:

```
GET     /logout                             com.feth.play.module.pa.controllers.Authenticate.logout
```

Which looks like this in the module code:

```
public static Result logout() {
    noCache(response());

    return PlayAuthenticate.logout(session());
}
```

The way the application works is there is a main.scala.html file with the css/js links that the web application needs and a mobile_main.scala.html page with the css/js that the contents of the mobile templates use. The problem I am having is that when I sign out of the application (either mobile or web) I get redirected to the index of the web application - index.scala.html. Is there anyway to change this so that I can be directed to the mobile index page when appropriate?

Thanks

Edit: This also applies to the page the application returns to after a successful login.

Ok after looking a bit further I traced the problem back to *Global.java*. I think I need to change the methods below to solve my problem. So that I can load a different page depending on an argument passed perhaps.

```
        @Override
        public Call login() {
            // Your login page
            return routes.Application.login();
        }

        @Override
        public Call afterAuth() {
            // The user will be redirected to this page after authentication
            // if no original URL was saved
            return routes.Application.index();
        }

        @Override
        public Call afterLogout() {
            return routes.Application.index();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the way is to save your state in the session, for example you can have two states: `mobile session` and `web session` and then verify this in condition before redirecting

```
if mobile session then redirect mobile index else redirect index
```